# Multiplication of two values in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am getting two value from select box 1)height & 2)width on change function i have to multiply height+width*2=price ,after this calculation i have to alert the price .

```
    var height =0 ; 
    var width =0 ;
    var price=0;
    $("#Heightproduct").change(function() { 
   h = $(this).val(); 
              var height = parseInt(h);
                price = height + width * 2;
                   alert(price);
                    });
                    $("#Widthproduct").change(function() { 
               w = $(this).val();
             var width = parseInt(w);
             price = height + width * 2;
                 alert(price);
                 });
```

Here is screen shot with out put.here i have selected height=25 width=25 and i am getting output in alert 50 it's wrong ,I want answer should be 100
[image: final output of my code]

Comment: `price = (height + width) * 2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like below. Avoid `var` for `width` and `height` inside the `change` event.

Also make it `(height + width) * 2` for operator precedence.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/jxQW3/)

```
var height = 0;
var width = 0;
var price = 0;
$("#Heightproduct").change(function () {
    h = $(this).val();
    height = parseInt(h); //Note the change here
    price = (height + width) * 2;
    alert(price);
});
$("#Widthproduct").change(function () {
    w = $(this).val();
    width = parseInt(w); //Note the change here
    price = (height + width) * 2;
    alert(price);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
  price = (height + width) * 2;
```

Because of precedence it's calculating wrong.

Docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

> Operator precedence determines the order in which operators are evaluated. Operators with higher precedence are evaluated first.

A common example:

```
3 + 4 * 5 // returns 23
```

Comment: In that case, the output for OP should have been 75 and not 50 right?

Comment: My guess is he selected in first combo,That is `25`  then calcuted as  `0+25*2`

Comment: There is an issue with scope for height and width in this case. Even I thought on similar lines initially, but if we look at the bottom of the screenshot, we can see both drop-downs have value as 25 and still alert shows 50.

Comment: @SanjayNakate: I was not the one who down-voted mate. So I can't tell the exact reason. My guess is that whoever down-voted thinks that the solution is simple enough and that you haven't done enough research. Good to know that the problem has been solved :)

Comment: Fine ,i will care from next time @Harry

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
price = (height + width) * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var height = 0 ; 
var width = 0 ;
var price= 0;
$("#Heightproduct").change(function() { 
    h = $(this).val(); 
    var height = parseInt(h);
    price = (height + width) * 2;
    alert(price);
}).change();
$("#Widthproduct").change(function() { 
    w = $(this).val();
    var width = parseInt(w);
    price = (height + width) * 2;
    alert(price);
}).change();
```